# Rest-Api Dynamic Image Path and Express Unless

Tags: node.js, express

I have a rest-api nodejs server code.
I created `public/icon/` folder in project root and add some icons there.
I want to see the image in this location `http://localhost:3000/public/icon/myicon.png`
And also I have some authentication functions so I use thats route for unless auth token,

```
auth.authenticateToken.unless = unless; //check authentication condition is met 



app.use(
    auth.authenticateToken.unless({ //does not require authentication pages
        path: [
            {url: "/google/auth", methods: ["GET"]},
            {url: "/^\/public\/icon\/([^\/]*)$/", methods: ["GET"]},

            {url: "/users/login", methods: ["POST"]},
            {url: "/users/register", methods: ["POST"]},


        ]
    })
)

app.use(express.json());
var publicDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/public'); 
app.use(express.static(publicDir)); 

app.get('/public/icon/:filename', (req, res) => {
    const filename = req.params.filename;
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'icon', filename);
    
    res.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
                        }
    });
});
```

I found this way to show pictures, but when I try to go `http://localhost:3000/public/icon/myicon.png` page I get `Unauthorized` but if I give the auth token I can see. How can I see this link without authentication.

If my method has some problems for the showing pictures you can advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `url` parameter, your regex is within quotes, so it's actually read as a string, instead of a regex.

So, remove the quotes:

instead of:

```
{url: "/^\/public\/icon\/([^\/]*)$/", methods: ["GET"]},
```

use:

```
{url: /^\/public\/icon\/([^\/]*)$/, methods: ["GET"]},
```